# How do i put a <td> in my <table> with php?

Tags: php, soap, html-table

I’m working on a php snippet and i made a table. I tried putting a td tag inside but when i do this, a lot disappears. This is a piece of my code:

```
//Use the functions of the client, the params of the function are in 
//the associative array
$params = array('customerid' => '1532');
$response = $soapclient->ca_customer_products($params);
echo '<table><tbody><tr><th>Product</th><th>Naam</th>   <th>Prijs</th><th>Qte</th></tr>';
echo '<table style="border-style: solid; border-width:1px;">';
foreach($response->list->element as $product) {
  if($product->stock > 0) {
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td style="display: flex; border: 1px solid black;">';
  //echo '<td>';
  echo '<img src="' . $product->url . '" class="php_image" style="width: 15%; height: 15%;"/>';
  //echo '<img style="width: 15%;">';
  //echo '</td>';
  print_r($product->description);
  echo "<p style='color:green;'>".$product->price1."</p>";
  echo "<p style='color:red; text-decoration: line-through'>".$product->price2."</p>"; 
  print_r($product->price1);
  print_r($product->price2);
  print_r($product->stock);
  echo '</tr>';  
  }
}
echo '</tbody></table>';
```

The code behind the // is where i tried to put the td tag but when i put it there, the images that normally appear go blank and when i inspect my code there is a lot of other code that also disappears. What am i doing wrong here?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: A td directly inside a td doesn't make sense to me. What are you trying to do? And why do you have a table directly inside a table? Your HTML is all over the place I'm afraid.

Comment: where is closing of td?

Comment: You don't have to use echo for each line, You can use echo only once for a long string.

Comment: I didn't realise my first td tag was also a td, i thought it was only for my css. I tried this now but it still doesn't seem to work: echo '<tr>';
      //echo '<td style="display: flex; border: 1px solid black;">';
      echo '<td>';
      echo '<img src="' . $product->url . '" class="php_image" style="width: 15%; height: 15%;"/>';
      //echo '<img style="width: 15%;">';
      echo '</td>';

Comment: You can't add a <td> inside another <td>.

Answer (score 0):

First I can see a problem with these lines :

```
echo '<table><tbody><tr><th>Product</th><th>Naam</th>   <th>Prijs</th><th>Qte</th></tr>';
echo '<table style="border-style: solid; border-width:1px;">';
```

Because you just close your first TABLE at the end, but not the other inside :

```
echo '</tbody></table>';
```

Comment: I was really confused with the styling in php but now i understand that i don't need to make another table tag just for the styling. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are some inconsistency of your `<td>` to `<th>`. You can have a look below

```
$params = array('customerid' => '1532');
$response = $soapclient->ca_customer_products($params);
echo '<table style="border-style: solid; border-width:1px;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Naam</th>   
            <th>Prijs</th>
            <th>Qte</th>
        </tr>
     </thead><tbody>';
foreach($response->list->element as $product) {
    if($product->stock > 0) {
        echo "<tr>
             <td style='display: flex; border: 1px solid black;'>   
                <img src='$product->url' class='php_image' style='width: 15%; height: 15%;'/>
             </td>
             <td>Your product name</td>
            <td>$product->description</td>
            <td>
                <p style='color: green;'>$product->price1</p>
                <p style='color: red;'>$product->price</p>
            </td>
            <td>$product->stock</td>
        </tr>";
    }
}
echo '</tbody></table>';
?>
```

Comment: Perhaps put the th tags inside of thead and the other rows in tbody.

Comment: `<<<TD`  doesn't seem fitting for tr data.

Comment: Yes @mickmackusa, I noticed that.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot problems with the code. From what i can see in your code, you have a table inside a tbody and at the end closed only one table.
Secondly you're also trying to put a td inside another td which is not the right thing to do. Check out [mozilla developer website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table)  for more information on using HTML tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Use the functions of the client, the params of the function are in 
//the associative array
$params = array('customerid' => '1532');
$response = $soapclient->ca_customer_products($params);
echo '<table style="border-style: solid; border-width:1px;"><tbody><tr><th>Product</th><th>Naam</th>   <th>Prijs</th><th>Qte</th></tr>';
foreach($response->list->element as $product) {
  if($product->stock > 0) {
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td style="display: flex; border: 1px solid black;">';
  //echo '<td>';
  echo '<img src="' . $product->url . '" class="php_image" style="width: 15%; height: 15%;"/>';
  //echo '<img style="width: 15%;">';
  //echo '</td>';
  print_r($product->description);
  echo "<p style='color:green;'>".$product->price1."</p>";
  echo "<p style='color:red; text-decoration: line-through'>".$product->price2."</p>"; 
  print_r($product->price1);
  print_r($product->price2);
  print_r($product->stock);
  echo '</td></tr>';  
  }
}
echo '</tbody></table>';
```

You are not closing your tags correctly. Also checkout [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Tables) just as @christopher_bincom has mentioned.